# How to select specific columns using Pyspark in Databricks

Tags: excel, apache-spark, pyspark, multiple-columns

I'm very new with Pyspark and Databricks so currently I'm stuck with this issue. I have an excel workbook sheet named Sales that contains 7000 rows and 35 columns. I want to make a Dataframe with Pyspark in DAtabricks based on only 5 columns from that workbook sheet. These 5 columns are located in B, C, D, E, and F. please see the image to check my code.[image]

Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Hi. you shouldn't put an image of you code, but simply copy/paste the code directly in the question. With all lines starting with 4 spaces. SO will color it for you.

Comment: Also, it'd be a good idea to copy/paste the output of display(FirstSheet) - and btw variable should start with lower case :)

Answer (score 0):

Salecting column in a dataframe is simple:

```
# create a dataframe with col B, C, D, E, and F 
bcdef = firstSheet.select("B", "C", "D", "E" "F")
bcdef.show
```

Note: you can find such info in many posts online, such as: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/select-columns-from-pyspark-dataframe/